# dot-notation for DUs prevent nesting

Tags: f#

With these two Discriminated Unions (DUs) :

```
type Premier = |M1 of int
type Second = |M2 of Premier
```

I can have these valid lines of code :

```
let p_1 = M1 42
let p_2 = 42 |> M1 
let p_3 = Premier.M1 42

let s_1 = M2 (M1 42)
let s_2 = 42 |> M1 |> M2
```

But the following nested ***dot*** syntax is not accepted (important difference with classes syntax) :

```
let s_3 = Second.M2.M1 42
```

**Question** : What is the fundamental reason it is so ? I mean are there conflicts or inconsistencies with other parts of F# syntax / grammar that prevent it ? Or does it result in type inference difficulties ?

**Follow-up** : I still have 2 ways (s_1 and s_2) to define my variable of type Second but is there a more idiomatic and concise third way for DUs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see why this should work. The two ways that work are the standard ways for creating a discriminated union that contains another value. The third option that you're trying does not make sense from the F# perspective. To explain a bit more:

- `M1 42` is a value of type `Premier`
- `M2` is a constructor that takes `Premier` and returns `Second`
- `M2 (M1 42)` calls the constructor with an argument - and so you get `Second`

With piping, the thing works exactly the same

- `42 |> M1` passes the `int` to the constructor `M1` resulting in `Premier` value
- `42 |> M1 |> M2` means `(42 |> M1) |> M2` - that is, it passes `Premier` value to the `M2` constructor and you get `Second.

As for your attempt to write `Second.M2.M1 42`, this is not valid because:

- `Second.M2` is a constructor (a function) that expects `Premier` and returns `Second`.
- A function does not have any members - so you cannod do `.` on a constructor.

Comment: Thanks. For "Second.M2.M1 42", I could imagine that Second.M2 (as a constructor that expects Premier) understands that I provide this Premier with the syntaxic sugar ".M1 42" as the ending part of "Second.M2.M1 42". Sure it would require that a dot after a function accepts subsequent constructors that are not part of its member list but are part of the members of the subtype it refers to. And this is certainly a problem. Is it ? At least, it requires that the type inference builds such a list and checks that the candidate is a valid one. (thanks again for your clear explanations). newbie in F#

Comment: type Second =  |M2 of Premier \n\t static member FM1 (x:int) :Second = M2 (M1 x) \n and then I can define : let s_3 = Second.FM1 42 if I really want dot notation for nested DUs. A bit convoluted though... I accept your answer of course.

Comment: @FZed Hmm, I see what you're trying to do. Using `static member` is the best way to do that. The problem is, this does not work if you had `M3 of Premier * Premier`, for example...